# In javascript, how to insert an array as an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's illustrate my question with some code to make you understand what I need.
I searched for a solution and they always propose to add the element of an array in another array. This is not what I want.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array_1 = [];
    var array_2 = [1,2,3];
    var array_3 = [4,5,6];
    array_1.push(array_2);
    array_1.push(array_3);
    alert(array_1);
</script>
```

This will show :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I would like to get

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6]
```

which means array_1 contains 2 elements : array_2 and array_3

I need that because I will loop array_1 which will print in the HTML the 3 elements of each array (array_2 and array3).

For example:

```
    var main_array = [];
    var title_1 = ["My title 1",16,"color:#000;"];
    var title_2 = ["My title 2",14,"color:#333;"];
    main_array.push(title_1);
    main_array.push(title_2);

    txt=""
    main_array.forEach(myFunction);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    function myFunction(value, index, array) {
    txt = txt + '<span style=\'font-size:' + value[1] + 'color:' + value[2] + '\'>' + value[0] + '</span><br>';
    }
```

I am showing this last example in case it doesn't exist the possibility to add an array inside an array in Javascript. Maybe someone will think of another solution to accomplish what I need to do.

Comment: Don't use `alert` to show your data. This is what [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) is for. `alert` will alter your data so it can be shown on your screen. You can open the console by pressing either **f12** or **ctrl + shift + i**.

Answer (score 2):

You do get `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`. It just doesn't seem like it since `alert` calls `toString`, which joins all the elements together with a comma. So, `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].toString() == [1,2,3].toString() + "," + [4,5,6].toString()` which is `"1,2,3" + "," + "4,5,6"` which is `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`. Just `console.log` it and you'll see it's a nested array.

Answer (score -1):

```
const array_1 = [1,2,3];
const array_2 = [4,5,6];
const array_3 = [[...array_1], [...array_2]];
```

Comment: Read the question.